# PDF files replaced by question mark icon in Dock

Tags: finder, dock

I have pdf files in the Dock of my MacBook Air, I just left them there and everything was fine, now all of a sudden a large question mark comes up and I can't open them.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where those files on a external drive or from a web page ?

Answer (score 1):

You can drag broken links out of the dock by click and drag them to the middle of the screen. Then use spotlight to locate the files - on your Mac or on a time machine backup before they went missing.